# my hover effect is taking the whole container

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

here I used bootstrap 5 to create my navbar that should collapse when screen size gets smaller. so I did small hover effect on the nav elements. however when they collapse my hover effects takes the whole space as you can see the results down and I just want the hover effect to be under the words only.
I tried to fix that and you can see my solution at end of CSS code but it does not work.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Reem Kufi Fun', sans-serif;
}

section {
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75)), url(background.jpg);
  min-height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
  background-position: center;
}

#navbar {
  background-color: transparent !important;
  padding: 2% 6%;
}

a {
  color: white !important;
}

#fsta {
  font-size: 2em;
}

li {
  padding-right: 2%;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
}
  ul li::after {
    content: "";
    height: 2px;
    background-color: #009688;
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    width: 0%;
    transition: 1s;
  }
  ul li:hover::after {
    width: 90%;
    cursor: pointer;
  }

.text {
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

  .text h1 {
    font-size: 4em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 4px;
    font-weight: 900;
  }

  .text p {
    font-size: 1em;
    padding: 0 6%;
    padding-top: 2%;
    line-height: 25px;
  }

  .text div {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
  }

    .text div button {
      text-transform: uppercase;
      width: 200px;
      padding: 15px 0;
      text-align: center;
      margin: 20px 10px;
      border-radius: 25px;
      font-weight: bold;
      border: 2px solid #009688;
      background-color: transparent;
      color: white;
    }
    .text div button:hover {
      background-color: #009688;
      transition: 1s;
    }


/* media queries */

@media(max-width:1523px) {
  .text h1 {
    font-size: 3.5em;
  }
}

@media(max-width:1227px) {
  .text p {
    font-size: 0.9em;
    padding: 0 3%;
    padding-top: 2%;
  }
}

@media(max-width:1028px) {
  .text p {
    padding: 0 0.1%;
  }
  .text h1 {
    font-size: 3.3em;
  }
}

@media (max-width:600px) {
  .text div {
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
  }
  .text p {
    display: none;
  }
}

@media (max-width:991px) {
  ul li::after {
    content: "";
    height: 2px;
    background-color: #009688;
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    width: 0%;
    transition: 1s;
  }
  ul li :hover::after {
    max-width: 50%;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-iYQeCzEYFbKjA/T2uDLTpkwGzCiq6soy8tYaI1GyVh/UjpbCx/TYkiZhlZB6+fzT" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lexend+Deca:wght@400;500;600&family=Reem+Kufi+Fun:wght@400;500;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-u1OknCvxWvY5kfmNBILK2hRnQC3Pr17a+RTT6rIHI7NnikvbZlHgTPOOmMi466C8" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<section>
  <nav id="navbar" class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-light">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <a id="fsta" class="navbar-brand" href="#">!Rb Rooms</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0 justify-content-end flex-grow-1">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" aria-current="page" href="#">HOME</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">BEDROOM</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">KITCHEN</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">DINNING</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">BACKYARD</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div class="text">
    <h1>Design your house</h1>
    <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Harum mollitia ipsam, praesentium porro iste eligendi quisquam Lorem ipsum </p>
    <div>
      <button> Watch more</button>
      <button> subscribe</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

tried several things but it didn't work for me at all and in the CSS code I left my solution at the end.

Comment: Please read the "*[ask]*" guidelines, specifically focusing on the "*[mcve]*" portion. We don't need your whole page, that just obscures the problem(s).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your CSS:

you made the li take display: block, so it takes up the whole width of the screen.
display: inline-block should do the trick and decrease max-width.

```
@media (max-width:991px) {
ul li::after {
content: "";
height: 2px;
background-color: #009688;
margin: auto;
display: inline-block;
width: 0%;
transition: 1s;
}
ul li:hover::after {
  max-width: 20%;
  cursor: pointer;
 }
```